# Maximum virtual attribute size in Unidata

Tags: u2, unidata, multivalue-database

I am receiving the following error when trying to retrieve data using a largish virtual attribute:

Virtual Attribute Error: Virtual field too big.

I have been unable to locate the maximum size allowed for a virtual attribute in the Unidata manuals. I am using Unidata 7.2, ECLTYPE Pick.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly I believe you will need to increase the size of the UDT environment variable VFIELDSIZE to accomodate the attribute in question. Perhaps set it to 400 and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Glenn, thanks for the answer. I tried instantiating the environment variable VFIELDSIZE = 600 as a Windows system variable and the command still failed in the same way. I suppose I need to go the basic subroutine route.